# Textfield not updating

Tags: swiftui

the following code loads fine, the text and the double field both show 300. however when I click submit the text only changes to 0. you will see in the print output that the init was called with the new value of 0 but it does not update the double field? any suggestions?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var amount:Double = 300
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.amount)")
            DoubleField(value: $amount)
            Button(action: {self.amount=0}) {Text("Submit")}
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct DoubleField:View {

    @Binding var doubleValue:Double
    @State var stringValue:String

    init(value: Binding<Double>) {
        print("DoubleField.init(value: \(value.wrappedValue))")
        self._doubleValue = value
        self._stringValue = State(initialValue: "\(value.wrappedValue)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("0.00", text: $stringValue)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SwiftUI doesn't have any idea that internal state of DoubleField  View changed. At the time you set `_stringValue`, `DoubleField` instance still doesn't exists, that is why you not able to write stringValue = ... in init(..) State property wrapper could inform SwiftUI only after initialization that its wrapped value was changed, not before.

try the next

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var amount:Double = 300
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.amount)")
            DoubleField(value: $amount).id(amount)
            Button(action: {
                self.amount += 10
            }) { Text("Submit") }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct DoubleField:View {

    @Binding var doubleValue:Double
    @State var stringValue:String
    init(value: Binding<Double>) {
        print("DoubleField.init(value: \(value.wrappedValue))")
        self._doubleValue = value
        self._stringValue = State(initialValue: "\(value.wrappedValue)")
        print(stringValue)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text(stringValue)
        TextField("20.00", text: $stringValue)
        }
    }

}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

all fields are updating as required, because SwiftUI see the change due the .id modifier

In your case just use

```
DoubleField(value: $amount).id(amount)
```

It works because Double conform to Hashable and it will recalculeta its body only when amount value changed.

**UPDATE**

You can create custom binding, as I did in next example. It is Binding with backend Double value wrapped with @State (to inform SwiftUI about any change of its value)

```
let binding = Binding<String>(get: {
            if self.empty { return "" } else {
                return self.format(value: self.value.value)
            }
        }) { (str) in
            self.empty = str.isEmpty
            // before string to double
            // replace decimal separator to "." !!!
            let dot = Locale.current.decimalSeparator ?? "."
            let s = str.replacingOccurrences(of: dot, with: ".")
            self.value.value = Double(s) ?? 0.0
        }
```

where

```
func format(value: Double) -> String {
        // for presentation
        // replace "." with decimal separator
        let dot = Locale.current.decimalSeparator ?? "."
        var s = String(format: "%f", value)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: dot)
        .reversed()
        .drop(while: {$0 == "0"})
        .reversed()
        .map(String.init)
        .joined()

        if let last = s.last, String(last) == dot {
            s.removeLast()
        }
        return s
    }
```

It works with TextField much better than Formatter build-in support in TextField and also support Locale dependent decimal separator

And example usage
[image]

usage

TextField("0", text: binding)

Comment: thank you this does work.  but it feels very hackish (like most things in swiftui currently lol) to me there has to be a better method.

Comment: so while researching this i found at that i can send non text values to a textfield using the value instead of text overload.  Which means that swiftui subclassed the textfield and has a way of updating the view that the bound value changed? So i dont even need to use the subclassed textfield but i am still curious in general how to alert the view that a bound value changed in a subview.

Comment: @eleethesontai see my update with custom binding. it works tap by tap with TextField

Comment: in your example did you use that binding variable as the text parameter in the textfield?

Comment: @eleethesontai yes

Comment: when i try to use a textfield with a custom binding around the  double value it does work at least it updates the value.  but the formating is choppy like if i try to type in 1000 as soon as i type in 1 it returns 1.00.  the formatters work smother so im going to for now use at textfield("", value:$amount, formatter:NumberFormatter)

Comment: @eleethesontai it works exactly as in the screenshot (copy (format(:Double) including!!) - paste - change self.value.value to your State wrapped double value).  i am not happy with numberformatter

Comment: @eleethesontai complete app, https://gist.github.com/op183/24607b6309f7d1ea8f3aaf02d17e4ed3