# How can a decimal number with a comma be converted in a decimal (Point) in SwiftUI?

Tags: formatting, decimal, swiftui, calculation

How can a textField were a comma is inserted be Formated so the inserted Decimal value example 10,05$ can be converted to a decimal(Point) 10.05$?

```
private static let Intrest = "Intrest"
private static let Repayment = "Repayment"



var loan: Double {
    let intrest = Double (Intrest)
    let repayment = Double (Repayment)

    let Loan = Intrest + Repayment

    return Loan
}



var body: some View {
     VStack{
        HStack{
           Text ("Repayment %")
           Spacer()
           TextField("2 %", text: $Repayment)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
      VStack{
         HStack{
            Text ("Loan / month")
            }
            TextField("2 %", text: $Loan)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
}
```

The problem only occurs because in many countries mostly comma is used which breaks the calculation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you convert your string into a double with point and not comma.

This one should help. 
[Swift playground - How to convert a string with comma to a string with decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313871/swift-playground-how-to-convert-a-string-with-comma-to-a-string-with-decimal)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [Textfield not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60511948/textfield-not-updating/60512709#60512709) and use custom string binding with double back storage.

Specifically read the Update there :-)

Complete example usage of custom string binding with backend double number is here https://gist.github.com/op183/24607b6309f7d1ea8f3aaf02d17e4ed3